# API Endpoint to Publish CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, cloudpage

I'm using an [API integration of VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergey-agadzhanov.AMPscript) which requires setting API access for the installed server-to-server package to include Channels: Web - Read + Write + Publish. That package doesn't have a publish ability to publish saved Cloud Pages landing pages.

Is there an API endpoint that will allow me to publish changes on a Cloud Page?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: An API was created to support the interactive email features from the RebelMail acquisition, but AFAIK, it has not been made public.  We can only hope.